# Is it possible to change the field name in user storage with a string?

Tags: actions-on-google

If you write conv.user.storage.something = "test" I understand that, but can you change the field name "something" in this example.  Say you had an array of values named Fruit ["Banana", "Apple"] can you read the array and then assign those values to the field name value.  It seems like you can only set the field name manually such as conv.user.storage.Banana but what if I am getting those names from an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can iterate through the array and directly assign the keys.

```
for (const element of array) {
  conv.user.storage[element] = "text"
}
```